# Magento 2 Add custom CSS class to breadcrumbs

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs, styles

I need to add my own CSS class to the `<ul>` tag in breadcrumbs.

in `Magento_Catalog/templates/products/breadcrumbs.pthml`
the code look like this

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"></div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            ".breadcrumbs": <?= $viewModel->getJsonConfigurationHtmlEscaped() ?>
        }
</script>
```

And this code is rendered to the following on frontend.

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"><!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<ul class="items">
    <li class="item home">          
        <a href="http://example.com/" title="Go to Home Page">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item product">    
        <strong>Test product</strong>           
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to add my own css class for example `.breadcrumb-style` to the `<ul>` tag.

What should I do? I did find the `_breadcrumb.less` file, which allow me to edit the exiting class like `.itmes`, but I don't know how to add more CSS classes.

Answer (score 2):

First create a new module for breadcrumbs.
you need to rewrite the css with your custom module using di.xml of your frontend scope:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" type="Namespace\Module\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs"/>
</config>
```

Then in your customized phtml file like namespace/module/view/frontend/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml, you can add your class:

```
<div class="breadcrumbs"><!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<ul class="items">
    <li class="item home">          
        <a href="http://example.com/" title="Go to Home Page">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item product">    
        <strong>Test product</strong>           
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and your customization css file:_breadcrumb.less will be going to 
namespace/module/view/frontend/web/css/source/ where you have your css changes:
_breadcrumb.less content:

```
.breadcrumbs {color: somecolor;}
```

Please look at the full example on [this resource](https://github.com/gr33nart/m2_greenart_breadcrumbs).

Comment: Does the module from GITHUB work for Magento 2.3.1? I just installed the extension, and added my own css class in breadcrumbs.phtml. but it has no effect on the site.

Comment: have you run php bin/magento setup:upgrade?

Comment: yes it is compatible.

Comment: also do the php bin/magento c:c

Comment: yes, I ran setup:upgrade and cleared the cache after activated the module. I'm actually quite comfortable working with custom extensions, so I guess I didn't miss anything. I tried to add my style to <ul class="items breadcrum-style">, but It has no effect on the frontend. It's the breadcrumb for product page I'm trying to edit. I guess this extension works for product page as well right. it's weird it's not affact.

Comment: are you sure that the phtml file that you are changing is being used? can you echo 1; echo exit(); and see 1 being printed?

Comment: I just did echo 1; echo exit(); you are right. it's not being used. I don't know what I missed then. I copy the module to app/code, I activated the module by bin/magento module:enable, and I did setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile, I cleared all static contents. I cleared cache. and I'm on developer mode. I suppose the module should be installed correctly... it's really weird.

Comment: do you see the module enabled in app/etc/config.php?

Comment: yes, it's says 'GreenArt_Breadcrumbs' => 1.

Comment: you probably have another customization of breadcrumbs somewhere else? can you give the location of phtml file that now it is being used? are you able to use template path hints?

Comment: Stores –> Configuration->developer advance template path hints

Comment: in the catalog_product_view.xml, it has this code,         <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Catalog::product/breadcrumbs.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>. maybe this file override the GreenArt module?

Comment: I'll keep trying to figure it out. I upvote your answer and accept it when I got it to work. thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @MagentoLearner no that is not a customization that is the core one coming from magento module.

Comment: @MagentoLearner I hope your issue will be resolved please let me know if you could find what's going on, I am curios.

Comment: I enabled the template hints, and the breadcrumbs is using this file vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/breadcrumbs.phtml. And GreenArt module suppose override this path, right?

Comment: @MagentoLearner correct

Comment: Hi @Nickool, I never got this to work. when I look at the block file, https://github.com/gr33nart/m2_greenart_breadcrumbs/blob/master/GreenArt/Breadcrumbs/Block/Html/Breadcrumbs.php, it seems this file need to be finished, do I need to write any code here?

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this file. /Magento_Theme/web/templates/breadcrumbs.html Try to copy this file in your theme folder and change in it according to your requirements. You can find in files <%- crumb.name %> i did the same thing as i want to change the class name.